# restore filesystem after fdisk

Tags: linux, partition, data-recovery, fdisk

I split a partition in two with `fdisk`, but after rebooting I've got partition in FAT filesystem (was ext4). What's can be wrong? And how to fix it or get data from bad partition? I hope this is possible.
List of commands what I did:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda3 300G
fdisk /dev/sda
//here I remove sda3 partition and create 2 new for sda3 and sda4.
//w and reboot...

//...and I've got this structure:
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3e74fdb8

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1           16065      626534      305235   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2          626535     6924014     3148740   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3   *     6924015   636069614   314572800   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       636069615  1465149167   414539776+  83  Linux
```

`mount` say me what he cannot read superblock so I've use `e2fsck` for start with some alternate superblock and try to use all superblocks from `mke2fs` output. Also I've try `mount -f -t ext4 /dev/sda3 tempdir`.

`testdisk` found all needed partition, but only in `[none]` search mode. As I understand, they output can use for fixing size of filesystem or for recovering data, but I don't understand her output.

```
Disk /dev/sda - 750 GB / 698 GiB - CHS 91202 255 63

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

   P ext3                     1   0  1    38 254 57     610464
   P FAT32                  431   0  1   561 254 63    2104515 [NO NAME]
   P ext4                   431   4 20 39593 132 25  629145600
   P ext4                 39593 128  5 91201  80 60  829079552

Write isn't available because the partition table type "None" has been selected.
```

Can someone tell me how to use this data for manually restore partition filesystem or move data to another partition?

Comment: Maybe you picked the wrong start offset when recreating sda3? In that case `testdisk` may be able to help. You should make a backup of your partition table (+data anyway) before making such changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, `fdisk` create wrong partition offset (*thanks to @frostschutz*). And `testdisk` couldn't found anything what I need with `[Intel]` and `not created with vista` options (he found only `sda2` partition). When I put `Yes` for his question about vista, he was find needed partition with `Deep search`. They was cannot be restored without deleting `sda2` and `sda4`. So I put `sda3` back (with deleting `sda2` and `sda4` partitions) and all my data comes back. After that I created new `sda2` and `sda4` partitions.
Also I try to use `PhotoRec` but restored files looks strange and it was be only files without my folders.